# WPF/Prism: Center InteractionRequest Popup

Tags: c#, wpf, prism

I am using Prism along with WPF.  Is there any way to center a popup over my application, and not the associated object?  I generally like to post some source code, but there really isn't much to post.  The only properties I see on the PopupWindowAction are IsModel and CenterOverAssociatedObject.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I see `WindowStartupLocation` property in PopupWindowAction near `IsModel` and `CenterOverAssociatedObject`
https://github.com/PrismLibrary/Prism/blob/master/Source/Wpf/Prism.Wpf/Interactivity/PopupWindowAction.cs

But i think, that it's not released yet